# Separate db for each users

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-8, laravel-10

how to create a database when the user register after username to create a database in MongoDB using Laravel. and I am using two databases MySQL(primary) and MongoDB.

I want to when the user register and automatically create a database in MongoDB

I don't know if is it possible or not.

Comment: Databases in MongoDB are created automatically. There is no "createDatabase" command.

Comment: Why do you need a separate DB per user? Unless you're running a SaaS operation this sounds like it is probably unnecessary, in most cases

Comment: Creating a new database per user is not recommended.  It's more practical to have a single database with separate collections for each user, or a common set of collections where documents contain a field indicating the user they belong to.